# Obj-C, can I use a different targets for my free and full version of my app with IAP?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'd like to use different targets for my free and full versions of my app.

I then want to setup in app purchases, so a full version upgrade can be purchased.

However, I'm unsure how I can modify the target to make it the full version. I assumed that the targets would be different binaries and therefore using targets for this purpose wouldn't work ?

The only example I've found is a simple NSUserdefaults flag, which seems very insecure and sounds very easy to crack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing  an In App Purchase, then you provide all the code in your App, but you put some branching logic that excludes the execution of the paid for stuff unless they have paid for it. There is no downloading of a full app one if they do it in app.

What you are discussing is having a free app and an paid app and the user can then go to the app store and purchase the paid for app separately.

Using NSUserDefaults for the In App Purchases isn't necessarily insecure - just encrypt the data before saving it to disk.

Comment: So I can't just use conditional target flags ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but that's the way to do it for two different apps. For IAP in your context, you would have all the code compiled in the one app. In a simplest case, you could have `if (userHasBoughtFullVersion) { addFullVersionFeatureButtonToDisplay } else { hideFullVersionFeatureButtonFromDisplay }`

Comment: Ahh right, so I still need targets for a different product name / id etc.

Comment: If you are doing more than one app. If you are doing In App Purchases, you just build and release one app with one target and one product name and one id. That one app contains ALL of the logic and code and it is up to you to code around allowing the user to do things based on whether they have bought it or not. You just have to code to display or hide elements of your app depending on whether there is a value set in a file that indicates if they have bought the full version or not. There is no further download other than a receipt.